# Can't install Pygame using conda

Tags: python, pygame, conda, anaconda3

I was trying to install Pygame module using conda.

I used this command:

```
conda install pygame
```

It gave me the following error:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pygame

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Then I used the following command:

```
conda install -c cogsci pygame
```

Output:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata         source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
Examining python=3.7: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 2/2     [00:00<00:00, 11.12it/s]-failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - pygame -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*']

Your python: python=3.7

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.
```

I have installed different modules using conda install like tensorflow, numpy, pandas,matplotlib and they are all working but it is giving me an error in pygame.
How do I fix it and install Pygame?

Comment: I get the same error while I'm trying to download Keras. U fortunately I deleted my environment and created a new environment. I think try this solution.

Comment: Or try `pip install pygame` while your env active. If it doesn't work, run your conda prompt as an administrator.

Comment: What do you understand from that error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pygame package at `cogsci` is 4 years old and only compatible with python2.7. If you want the latest version use `pip install pygame`. Personnally I use the conda package at `evindunn` which is only  available for linux-64

Comment: I used to use pygame using conda on Linux Mint and it was working fine. Now I am using windows and it didn't work. Anyway I switched to pip environment and everything is working fine now. Thank you :)